Is the sequence $1,2,3,5,8,13,21 ...$ (Fib starting with 1,2) a Sidon/$B_2$ sequence
A $B_2$ or a Sidon sequence is a sequence such that all pairwise sums are distinct.
For example the sequence 1,2,8,9, is not a B_2 sequence, because $2+8 = 1+9$.
I have the feeling such a sequence (1,2,3,5,8,12,21,34... each number is the sum of the two prior) should be a B_2 sequence but I don't manage to prove it.
My computer programmed checked that this sequence is indeed a Sidon sequence at least for the 1000 first "Fibonacci"  numbers (with the $0,1$ usually at the beginning).
This subject may appeal to people familiar with the Zeckendorf’s theorem, that states the following:

every positive integer can be written uniquely as a sum of one or more non-consecutive Fibonacci numbers

but I don't see how one could use such a property to tackle the issue.
If any one has a hint of how one might go on to prove or disprove the statement, I would be very grateful.

I suggest: use the fact that the sequence grows very rapidly.  Note: you meant to write 2+8=1+9

I don't see how that could be enough, could you be more precise maybe or produce some other condition that explains that the property holds ? just corrected the sum thx

The sequence grows far too quickly. To see that:
Remark that, if $a>b$ then $F_a+F_b\leq F_{a+1}$.
So, suppose $F_n+ F_m= F_a+F_b$ and say that $n$ is the largest index and that $a>b$.  Then the right hand is at most $F_{a+1}$ . We also have $n\geq a+1 $ and $F_m>0$ so the left hand is strictly greater than $F_{a+1}$ so we are done.
